# Intersection of player and mesh

Tags: collision-detection, geometry

I have a 3D scene, and a player that can move about in it.

In a time-step the player can move from point A to point B.  The player should follow the terrain height but slow going up cliffs and then fall back, or stop when jumping and hitting a wall and so on.

In my first prototype I determine the Y at the player's centre's X,Z by intersecting a ray with every triangle in the scene.  I am not checking their path, but rather just sampling their end-point for each tick.  Despite this being Javascript, it works acceptably performance-wise.

[image: a bad collision; player shouldn't be half-out of the room]

However, because I am modeling the player as a single point, the player can position themselves so that they are half-in a cliff face and so on.  I need to model them as as a solid e.g. some cluster of spheres or a even their fuller mesh.  I am also concerned that if they were moving faster they might miss the test altogether.

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

Have a collision mesh that you don't render and is smaller than the room by the maximum diameter of the player. In this case the collision mesh could be much less detailed than then visible model helping performance.